# Can't assign to function call python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't see what the error is in my code below. Every time I try to compile, I get can't assign to function call. The error is in the last line.

```py
value = i_0(k);

xvalue = value*delta_x;

I1 = -0.5*(xvalue + d)*math.exp(-xvalue/d) + 0.5*d;

I2 = 0.5*d - 0.5*(d + M*delta_x - xvalue)*math.exp(-(M*delta_x - xvalue)/d);

I3 = 0.5*xvalue*math.exp(-xvalue/d);

I4 = 0.5*(M*delta_x - xvalue)*math.exp(-(M*delta_x - xvalue)/d);

#Error in this line
avg_ell(k) = I1 + I2 + I3 + I4 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the value of `avg_ell` it's hard to say what you intended, but `()` is how a function gets called in Python.

If you are trying to index assignment, you need to use `[]` instead:

```
avg_ell[k] = I1 + I2 + I3 + I4 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the type of value associated for "value" variable using type(value). If i_0 is a function, make sure it returns an integer or float value. Because I1, I2, I3 and I4 are mathematical expressions dependent on "value" variable.

If i_0 is a list. Verify whether i_0[k] is a valid result for those mathematical expressions. Also, consider the value of delta_x, it should reproduce xvalue a valid result for mathematical expressions used.

It will be highly speculative until you provide the actual values or types of the concerned variables in the code snippet.

Is avg_ell a list ? And are you assigning/replacing an indexed value ? If replacing use [] to index the value. If assigning a new index value, make sure that new index number is not of range. And don't forget to use [] to index the value.

As cwallenpoole said () is always used to call something.